# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../Images'

Tags: python, image, file-upload, jupyter-notebook

I am a beginner on Python. I try to open a picture to print its size and format. My picture is in several folders:

- /content/lymphoma_classifier/Images
- /content/lymphoma_classifier/ImageLoader.py

I have already wrote only the name of the picture, then the exact path but nothing works (my picture is in .tiff).

Here is my code :

```
"""importing pickled image_loader.obj created for ease of development, ImageLoader object created if pickled object not available"""
if 'image_loader.obj' in os.listdir('..'):
    with open('../image_loader.obj', 'rb') as f:
        image_data = pickle.load(f)

    eda = ExploratoryDataAnalysis(image_data)

else:
    image_data = ImageLoader('../Images')
    eda = ExploratoryDataAnalysis(image_data)
```

and my error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-ec6f79e79c9b> in <module>()
      7 
      8 else:
----> 9     image_data = ImageLoader('../Images')
     10     eda = ExploratoryDataAnalysis(image_data)

/content/lymphoma_classifier/ImageLoader.py in __init__(self, top_img_dir)
     19         self.top_img_dir = top_img_dir
     20         """get the cancer types from the subdirectory names and their full paths"""
---> 21         self.cancer_types = [cancer_type for cancer_type in os.listdir(self.top_img_dir)]
     22         self.img_dirs = [os.path.join(self.top_img_dir, cancer_type) for cancer_type in self.cancer_types]
     23 

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../Images'
```

Comment: the error is stating that the folder doesn't exist. You use a relative path which can be tricky. It depends on where you are executing the code. My advise would be to use full path to avoid this issue. Is the piece of code you have copied here included in the ImageLoader file or does it live somewhere else?

Comment: What is the current directory when you launch your script?